# Make URLs clickable in Eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, hyperlink, console

Is there a way to turn URLs in the Eclipse console into actual links? It should work without any kind of plugin.

Most other questions and howtos just deal with links to files, which apparently works with the pattern (File.java:1). But is there a solution for URLs (e.g. `http://example.org/`)?

Answer (score 4):

The conversion of `<filename>:<line number>` in to a hyperlink happens inside the [code of the console itself](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.jdt.debug/ui/3.6.100/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/debug/ui/console/JavaExceptionConsoleTracker.java#JavaExceptionConsoleTracker.matchFound%28org.eclipse.ui.console.PatternMatchEvent%29).  It's parsing the plain text looking for the pattern, then replacing it with an `IHyperlink` to the file inside your workspace.

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to configure the standard Eclipse console to resolve general URLs in a similar way.  There may be a plugin that does so, or you could change the pattern matcher used by default to create `IHyperlink` objects that would open up the internal web browser to that URL.